# Initialize database only when running Test using Spring java based configuration

Tags: java, database, spring, configuration, h2

I have the code to create data source and run scripts to create schema and add in data using java based spring configuration. I want to run those scripts only in test mode. Is there any annotation that I need to specify on top of the database initializer bean that would do the job?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @profile annotation for this, like:

```java
@Configuration
@Profile("test_profile")
public class StandaloneDataConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
    // do data source creation/initialization
    }
}
```

Then use:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class,
    classes={StandaloneDataConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test_profile")
public class TransferServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private TransferService transferService;

    @Test
    public void testTransferService() {
        // test the transferService
    }
}
```

You can read [this](http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles/) blog post from the Spring team to learn more details.

Comment: I can do it by using two separate Java Configurations but how can I do it using a single java config file?